# How TQuery give data to a TDatasource

Tags: delphi, bde

English is not my Native language sorry for the typing mistakes.

I know this is a newbie question but i am unable to solve this problem.

In Delphi 5 we can do this `TDatasource.Dataset = TQuery object`.
but i was trying to find how TQuery is internally passing the data to the TDatasource object.

I went through the TQuery class definition in  DBTABLES.pas but didn't fond anything helpful.

Please help.

Comment: See : `TDataLink` :http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+17+Writing+Database+Components/The+Data+Link/

Comment: Why do you want to know? What is your actual issue?

Comment: @JanDoggen Just to Understand how the components passing data to another one.

Comment: That is very hard and complex place of VCL, which started as BDE ISAM bridge, and then year after year had to be modified into more and more SQLish direction. Very intertwines with lot og legacy code and workarounds around it. Bat luck. There was some Joanna in Team Borland, who made a great three-parts article on db-aware internals. Then Embarcadero offended her, as usual, and she removed all Delphi-related materials from her site. I no even more remember her surname... But maybe you would somehow find it.

Comment: "I went through the TQuery class definition in DBTABLES.pas"  - of course, Did you read something about OOP ? It does not belong to TQuery, and it does not belong to declarations, it is internal and general behavior. Because it is general - you have to look at TCustomDataSet or something like that. Because it is internal - you have to look in implementations, not in declarations.